# Unity Image Component for 2D Animation

Tags: animation, 2d, sprite, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a 2D game in Unity (Version 5.1.2) which has an animation. 
 
The animation is generated by flipping through the sprites in the sprite sheet. 
My problem is that the animation is playing as it should in the "Scene View" but not in "Game View".
I normally create animations by using the sprite editor and then drag & drop all the sprites on the screen (Scene View). 
It creates a Sprite Renderer to switch the sprites but I would like the Image Component to flip through the sprites. It seems like only sprites in the Image Component is being displayed in the "Game View". 
Is there any way I can get some assistance on this please.

Answer (score 1):

Its really strange that you are only seeing that in your Scene View. If the animation is your default animation? Otherwise, make sure that you are sending the right parameters to your animator. A good way to test it is opening your Animator windows, checking all transitions, and manually filling the parameters to see how it works wile the game is running. Also, check if the transitions between animations has exit times and transition durations, and disable them.